# Replace Certain Characters in a Text File in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with text sample:

```
+ Starting at line 0 $/A/B/C/Demo\Demo.sln
+ class string foo{ 
+      return "a\b"; 
+ }
```

I want to replace the \ slash in line with the path to /. But it should change the \ in other parts of code. I have to use Powershell for this. Expected Code:

```
+ Starting at line 0 $/A/B/C/Demo/Demo.sln
+ class string foo{ 
+      return "a\b"; 
+ }
```

Comment: Will it always be the same path? What’s constant around it? C:?

Comment: yes, C:/Demo will be constant

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be to use `Test-Path $string -IsValid` function (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7)) on every string in your file that contain at least one '\' character, for this you can split the text in your file on whitespaces and check which one of the resulting strings match the regex `'.*\\.*'`.

The result could be something like this:

```
$text = Get-Content -Path 'C:\...\data.txt'
$text -split '\s' | ForEach-Object {
    #find strings with \ only
    if($_ -match '.*\\.*') {
        #if the string is like a path
        if(Test-Path $_ -IsValid) {
            #replace \ with /
            $replace = $_ -replace '\\','/'
            #replace path string with fixed path (note: [regex]::escape(...) is necessary to avoid using regex in this replace, because $_ contains some characters like \ end similar)
            $text = $text -replace [regex]::escape($_), $replace
        }
    }
}

$text > 'C:\...\result.txt'
```

Comment: I can have multiple strings in file with \ which i do not want to replace, I want to replace only in those strings which are paths. I do not have a text i have a file called data.text

Comment: $text is a variable in which you can store the data into your file (e.g. using `$text = Get-Content $filePath`). With the script above you can replace all \ characters with / 
in all and only the strings that represent a path. Using the method `Test-Path $sometext -IsValid` you can check if the string inside `$sometext` is a path or not if you want to know more about this method please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7)
--
I've edited the above script to get data and save on another file

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a line-by-line match for a path specification and when found, replaces all backslashes in that part with forward slashes.

```
$file   = 'D:\Test\blah.txt'
$result = switch -Regex -File $file {
    '^(.*)\s([a-z]:[\\/](?:[^:*?"<>|\r\n])*)' { 
        '{0} {1}' -f  $matches[1], ($matches[2]-replace '\\', '/')
    }
    default { $_ }
}

# output on screen
$result

# overwrite file
$result | Set-Content -Path $file -Force
```

The output would be something like

```
+ Starting at line 0 C:/Demo/Demo.sln
+ class string foo{ 
+      return "a\b"; 
+ }

+ Starting at line 0 C:/Demo/AnotherDemo.sln
+ class string bar{ 
+      return "b\a"; 
+ }
```

Regex details:

```
^                          Assert position at the beginning of the string
(                          Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .                       Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *                    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)                         
\s                         Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
(                          Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   [a-z]                   Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z”
   :                       Match the character “:” literally
   [\\/]                   Match a single character present in the list below
                           A \ character
                           The character “/”
   (?:                     Match the regular expression below
      [^:*?"<>|\r\n]       Match a single character NOT present in the list below
                           One of the characters “:*?"<>|”
                           A carriage return character
                           A line feed character
   )*                      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: the path will not be the same. Starting at line would be there, but the number and path can change. so could use like 'Starting at line \d+ of' something like regex?

Comment: @PrakashKumar Did you try it? The regex searches for a path specification, it doesn't matter what the path is. The only path you need to change is for `$file`

Comment: yup, it did not work. there will be multiple paths in file

Comment: the path would not be same......it would be like $/A/B/C/D/....then something....A B C D would be fixed and sign

Comment: @PrakashKumar that doesn't make sense to me.. the regex picks up **any** local path in the file, so what path are you talking about? That is why I included one extra in your example.

Comment: @PrakashKumar The line `$file   = 'D:\Test\blah.txt` is an example. You need to enter the path to the file as it is on **your** computer of course. Also, in Windows, the path separator character is a backslash, not a forward slash, so why do you want to have the paths like that??